# Get current page's parameter after SetNavigationState

Tags: uwp

After calling `SetNavigationState` on a `Frame`, how can I get the navigation parameter that was passed to the current page (in a previous execution of the app)?

Other pages' parameters can be obtained using entries from the `BackStack` and `ForwardStack`, but the current page is in neither of these.

I'm writing a navigation service for a library, so I don't control the `Page` classes that are navigated to.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Remarks** of [Frame.SetNavigationState method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.setnavigationstate), it declared that

> Calling **SetNavigationState** will call [Page.OnNavigatedTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) for the current page, with **NavigationMode.Back**.

So to get the navigation parameter that was passed to the current page, we can use `OnNavigatedTo` method like following:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter.ToString();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Page` is not mine (this is for a "navigation service" in a library), so I can't add code to it. :(

Comment: @SolalPirelli Since you are writing a navigation service for a library, then this will depend on your implementation. I'm not sure how you implement your "navigation service", however, you may refer to the [NavigationService](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Template10%20(Library)/Services/NavigationService) in Template10 which has a [CurrentPageParam property](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zhDUQ.jpg) represents the navigation parameter that was passed to the current page.

Comment: Template10 stores the current param in the settings and fetches it back later, which is perfectly doable, but I find it a little silly; obviously it's stored somewhere in memory, there just doesn't seem to be any API to get it. :/

Comment: Template 10 stores it in memory.